# Associate Elastic IP with scheduled AWS data pipeline

Tags: elastic-ip, aws-data-pipeline

Anybody knows is it possible to associate Elastic IP with scheduled data pipeline? I have configured data pipeline to run every day. During data pipeline execution, I need access to Google DB. To have access to Google DB I should add IP (CIDR) in DB authorization settings. But without known public IP of EC2 instance created by data pipeline I cannot configure it.

So I need to have a possibility to setup Elastic IP once to be used for EC2 instance which is creating automatically by data pipeline each time when data pipeline is runned by scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware how you can associate a EIP, however, you can create a VPC with with a [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html).  When you create your EC2 put it in your subnet that you've created and if everything is setup properly then your public IP will always be the same.

A second option would be to run your pipeline on a [Task Runner](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-how-task-runner-user-managed.html).